# How to permute list of data.frame and create its annotated stack bar plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, annotations

I have list of data.frame that needed to be permuted first and create annotated stack bar plot for each data.frame. I have searched related post in SO and got some idea how to do it. However, I gave my shot how to make this as I expected, but my code is slow if data.frame is rather big, while getting stack bar plot is not desired. So I am continously reading ggplot2' vignette to get solution. I am stucked with permuting data.frame list in desired way. How can I permute list of data.frame and create its annotated stack bar plot ? Can anyone give me idea how to do this easily and efficiently ? How to manipulate list of data.frame and get annotated stacked bar plot(number of observation, label) ? Thanks in advance

reproducible data.frame :

```
confirmedDF <- list(
  bar = data.frame(begin=seq(2, by=11, len=25), end=seq(8, by=11, len=25), score=sample(54,25)),
  cat = data.frame(begin=seq(5, by=8, len=35), end=seq(9, by=8, len=35), score=sample(45,35)),
  foo = data.frame(begin=seq(8, by=13, len=25), end=seq(17, by=13, len=25), score=sample(49,25))
)

discardedDF <- list(
  bar = data.frame(begin=seq(3, by=12, len=40), end=seq(8, by=12, len=40), score=sample(72,40)),
  cat = data.frame(begin=seq(9, by=15, len=50), end=seq(17, by=15, len=50), score=sample(60,50)),
  foo = data.frame(begin=seq(21, by=19, len=30), end=seq(32, by=19, len=30), score=sample(42,30))
)
```

then my input list of data.frame :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

names(confirmedDF) <- paste("confirmed", names(confirmedDF), sep = ".")
names(discardedDF) <- paste("discarded", names(discardedDF), sep = ".")
merged <- do.call(rbind, c(confirmedDF, discardedDF))
merged %<>% rownames_to_column(var = "cn")
merged %<>% separate(cn, c("list", "letters", "seq"), sep = "\\.")
merged %<>% mutate(stringency = ifelse(score >= 12, "Stringent", "Weak"))

res <- merged %>% split(list(.$letters, .$stringency, .$list))
```

my attempt to get each individual stack bar plot, trivial code as follows :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

lapply(res, function(ele_) {
  plot_data <- ele_ %>%
    group_by(sample, stringency, list) %>%
    tally %>%
    group_by(sample, stringency) %>%
    mutate(percentage = n / sum(n), cumsum = cumsum(percentage))

  ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = sample,  y= n ,fill = stringency)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat = "identity")
})
```

I don't understand using lapply to get each bar plot is quite slow and inefficient. above trivial code didn't give my desired bar plot. How can I optimize the code? How to permute list of data.frame and getting its annotated bar plot ?

How can I achieve my desired output stack bar plot ? Any idea ?

Comment: In general, I'd recommend providing minimal examples. There seems to much ballast in this posting, which scares readers off. For example, why the different samples and the columns seq, begin, end etc.

Comment: @lukeA I got these two list as an output of my custom function, so I need to filter each by given threshold, also I could get list of csv files. However, getting stack bar plot of each sample is desired.  Thanks a lot

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the `res` example that you provided.

Comment: @lukeA I updated the thread. Now error is gone. Plus, how can I annotate each bar with actual number of observation ? How can I make it ?

Comment: You can use `+ geom_text(aes(label=n), position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5))` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
res %>% 
  bind_rows %>% 
  group_by(stringency, list, sample) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  setNames(c("var", "val", "sample", "n")) %>% 
  {bind_rows(., setNames(., c("val", "var", "sample", "n")))} %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=var, y=n, fill=val)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=n), position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  facet_wrap(~sample)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great solution. appreciated :)